# Debug react third party dependency

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I have a project that uses widgets written in `React`, those widgets are rendered the following way:

```
const element = document.getElementById('some element');

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyWidgetProvider>
        <MyWidget width={250} height={200} />
    </MyWidgetProvider>,
    element
);
```

Widgets are communicating with the main application using `OpenAjax pub/sub`, so if I start react app using `npm start` I don't have 100% possibility to debug it.

But if I rebuild full application then I have built react widget app with minified source, so I can't use debuggers in it, the only way to debug it I found using `console.log`, so is there any way to run or build react app in debug mode?